# Seemingly simple block matrix

Tags: matrices, block

I have a seemingly simple block matrix that I want to set with as few dependencies as possible. I already have amsmath and friends loaded. The only thing I'm intent on avoiding is blkarray.

Here is what I want to make:

[image: What I want to make]

Here is a failed attempt of mine, which produces the most heinous spacing imaginable with lines that don't meet to make corners.

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}[ccc]
        J_1 & \begin{array}{|cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\\ \cline{1-2}
        \begin{array}{cc|}0&0\\0&0\end{array} & J_2 & \begin{array}{|cc}0&0\\0&0\end{array}\\ \cline{2-3}
        \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc|}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array} & J_3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Which is ugly as all get-out:

[image: My nasty failed attempt at it]

NB: I have modified pmatrix so it takes column specs as an optional argument. Just pretend it is an array.

My difficulty seems to stem from the fact that I want 2x2 blocks, while most others I've seen seem to skate by using either multirow or multicolumn, but not both.

Edit:
This isn't nearly as ugly, but the vertical lines only cover half the distance of the multirow:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{cccccc}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$J_1$}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                                                   & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \cline{1-4}
        0 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$J_1$}} & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 &                                           & & 0 & 0\\ \cline{3-6}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$J_1$}} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & \\
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Better, but still not there.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental part of the matrix construction looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}
\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{ c c | c c | c c }
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & & 0 & \mc{0} & 0 & 0 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$J_1$}} & 0 & \mc{0} & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{1-4}
    0 & 0 & & & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$J_2$}} & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    0 & \mc{0} & 0 & 0 & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    0 & \mc{0} & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$J_3$}}
  \end{array}
  \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Perhaps it would be best to assign variables to the other components (like `A` and `B`) in order to maintain the matrix spacing.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get me what I want. When I added content to some of the zeros, it pushed the Js out of alignment, which I manually adjusted. Q1) How did you arrive at .6\normalbaselineskip? Q2) Can you think of a way to make the spacing automatic? Q3) Could you elaborate  on your final comment about assigning labels to components?

Comment: @Timtro: (Q1) `.6` is half of `1.2`, the new `\arraystretch` that I set. And, since you want the Js to be raised half the row height into position, I used `.6\normalbaselineskip`. (Q2) What spacing? (Q3) I was thinking along [these lines](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IbXWp.png), since it would keep the structure of the matrix consistent, rather than spreading things out horizontally and vertically due to A, B and C's shape/size.

Comment: (Q2) I meant the extent of the raisebox, so one needn't manually adjust. (Q3) You mean to beautify the code, rather than the typeset product, right?

Comment: @Timtro: (Q2) You can use `\multirow` (from the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow); (Q3) I actually means the typeset product. In many cases, the code might be very messy, but the output is beautiful. In this case, it seems like using variables keeps *both* neat and tidy. But I don't know the actual use-case and therefore can only suggest something.

Comment: I see what you mean now, WRT (Q3). I agree, and perhaps will do it. This was the motivation behind defining these Js in the first place: they are large and unsightly. WRT (Q1), This basically means combining my last attempt from last night (the edit below my original post) with your fantastic `\mc` trick. I tried it, and works famously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{pmatrix}` (of `amsmath`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, cells and columns. It's possible to use those nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
\Block{2-2}{J_1} & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \Block{2-2}{J_2} & & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &                  & & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block{2-2}{J_3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1-|1) |- (3-|5) -- (7-|5) ;
  \draw (1-|3) |- (5-|7) -- (7-|7) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

If you don't want to use Tikz explicitely, you can also specify the borders of the blocks with the key `borders` of the command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
\Block[borders={left,bottom,right}]{2-2}{J_1} & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                              & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \Block[draw]{2-2}{J_2} & & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &                        & & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block[borders={left,top,right}]{2-2}{J_3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.