# partitioned matrix

Tags: matrices

Please tell me the way to code latex to produce a matrix whose form is in the following image. Many thanks. My current code is not the desired one. [image: matrix]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    U^{(k+1)}_a=
    \left(
    \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
    &  &  &  &  & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{0k} \\
    &  &  &  &  & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{1k} \\
    &  &  U^{(k)}_a  &  &  & \vdots \\
    &  &  &  &  & \vdots \\
    &  &  &  &  & \vdots \\
    \hline
    a_k & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \left (U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{kk}
    \end{array}
    \right).
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You have much better chances of getting an answer if you provide a minimal working example. A good starting point for you might be the second answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/horizontal-row-separation-line-in-tikz-matrix-like-hline-in-tabular).

Comment: this might help: [Seemingly simple block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216454)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you, I have read the code but maybe it's too complicated to me. Thus, I expect a simpler one.

Comment: @SandyG: Thank you for your replying. I will do it for the next times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `\multicolumn` command. The `\cline` command makes the partial horizontal line. The 1-column `\multicolumn` in the last row eliminates the last portion of the vertical line. Using `\multicolumn` for the `U^{(k)}_a` entry automatically centers it horizontally instead of placing it in the third column.

I also added a bit of space between your rows by setting `\arraystretch` to `1.6`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
U^{(k+1)}_a=
\left(
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
&  &  &  &  & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{0k} \\
&  &  &  &  & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{1k} \\
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{U^{(k)}_a} & \vdots \\
&  &  &  &  & \vdots \\
&  &  &  &  & \vdots \\
\cline{1-5}
a_k & 0 & \dots & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \left (U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{kk}
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also probably delete the 4th column and two of the rows of `\vdots`, and use `\cdots` instead of `\dots`, but that's just my opinion. If you add `\usepackage{array}` you'll get a cleaner join between the horizontal and vertical lines.

```
U^{(k+1)}_a=
\left(
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
&  &  &  & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{0k} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{U^{(k)}_a} & \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{1k} \\
&  &  &  & \vdots \\
\cline{1-4}
a_k & 0 & \cdots & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \left (U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{kk}
\end{array}
\right).
```

[image]

Comment: Totally awesome! Thank you, Sandy G, not only because of helping me code but also guiding me to post question properly.

Comment: I should add, though it may seem strange, that comments should not be used for giving thanks. The way to show appreciation is to vote up an answer that you like (using the voting arrows to the left of the answer). Note that you can vote up more than one answer. [You should also "accept" the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a two-by-two matrix, with nested ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
U'=\left(
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
U & \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} a \\ b \\ \vdots \end{array} \\
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{
  \begin{matrix} a & b & \cdots \end{matrix}
} & z
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your reply. It's greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to have more dots without interruption, you may wish to use `tikz`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 \begin{document}
 \[U'~=~\left(
 \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[matrix of math nodes] (mymat) {
    &  & ~& \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{0k} \\
    &  & ~& \left(U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{1k} \\
    & ~~~~~~{\text{\Huge$U$}}~~~~~~ & &  \\[1cm]
  ~  &  & ~ & ~ \\
 a   &  &  & \left (U^{(k+1)}_a\right)_{kk}\\
 };
 \draw (mymat-1-4.north west) -- (mymat-5-4.north west);
 \draw (mymat-4-1.south west) -- (mymat-4-3.south east);
 \draw[ultra thick,line cap=round,dash pattern=on 0 off 1.6mm](mymat-2-4)--(mymat-4-4);
 \draw[ultra thick,line cap=round,dash pattern=on 0 off 1.6mm](mymat-5-1)--(mymat-5-4);
 \end{tikzpicture}}}\right)
 \]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. With that environment, the rules specified by `\Hline` (similar to `hline`) and the specifier `|` in the preamble are not drawn in the virtual blocks delimited by the commands for continuous dotted lines (`\Vdots` and `\Cdots`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$U' = 
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|c}[xdots/shorten=4pt,left-margin=2pt]
\Block{3-3}{U}
  &   &        & a \\
  &   &        & b \\
  &   &        & \Vdots \\
\Hline
a & b & \Cdots & z 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]