# How to write a matrix like this

Tags: matrices

How to write a matrix like this 
[image]

I tryed this

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
J_0 & O &\cdots\\
0& J_{n+1} & 0\cdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

I don't know how to do

Comment: There are dozens of block matrix questions on the site, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216458/82917.

Comment: @campa how to do the points between J_r and J_{n+1}

Comment: That's simply `\ddots`.

Comment: @campa it do not work

Comment: @PolineSandra - Please be more specific as to what "it do[es] not work" entails.

Comment: there is many detached lines

Comment: how to do juste one 0 not many 0@campa

Comment: @PolineSandra Please read [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 3):

Does one of these examples work for you?

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\(
    \begin{pmatrix}
        J_0    & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
        0      & J_{n+1} & \cdots & 0      \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0      & 0       & \cdots & J_r
    \end{pmatrix}
\)
\(
    \begin{pmatrix}
        J_0    & 0       & \cdots &     \\
        0      & J_{n+1} & \cdots &     \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots &     \\
               &         &        & J_r
    \end{pmatrix}
\)
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]
I personally like the left one better, it leaves less room for mis-interpretation.

See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for why I used `\(` `\)` instead of `$$` `$$`.

Comment: Thank you, see if you can help me here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434179/how-to-write-nilpotente-matrix

Comment: @PolineSandra Surely this answer simply duplicates the question you link to in your comment?  And please, instead of just posting images in your questions, please show complete compilable code that shows what you've tried.

Comment: @PolineSandra In addition to what Alan Munn wrote, with which I completely agree, if this answer solves your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: no it is not the same i have a decalage 4 colums at 1 5 in the second line how to do ?

Comment: It is not exactly the same matrix, but you should be able to rework this answer to output the matrix in the other question. The macros and environments are the same.

Comment: @MaxSnippe i tryed this:     \(N_{m+l}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0    & 1  &0  &   & \cdots & 0      \\
        0    & 0  &1 &0 &\cdots & 0      \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \ddots &  \\
        0      & 0       & \cdots &  & &1\\
        0 &0&\cdots &\cdots &\cdots &0
    \end{pmatrix}
\)

Comment: Try adding backslashes to the opening- and closing parenthesis `(` and `)`

Comment: i do \ before ( and )  but in the message it do not appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78208/discussion-between-max-snippe-and-poline-sandra).